# Undefined method 'pop' in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, methods

I have this code

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  long_word = ""
  sentence.split(" ").sort_by {|x| x.length}
  long_word = sentence.pop

  return long_word
end

p longest_word("hello dogs are fast")
```

And I get the error that the method 'pop' is undefined when I try running it. Does this have something to do with gemfiles? I thought I set that stuff up already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling array method `pop` on a string `sentence`, not a received from `split` array of strings.

By the way, your code can be simplified:

```
def longest_word(sentence)
  sentence.split(' ').sort_by(&:length).pop
end

p longest_word("hello dogs are fast")
#=> "hello"
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/yHH/1)

You can also use [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
sentence.split(" ").max_by(&:length)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/yHH/3)

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `pop` on `sentence`, which is a String.

You probably want this:

```
long_word = sentence.split(" ").sort_by {|x| x.length}.pop
```

Answer (score 0):

`split` and `sort_by` do not change the variable in any way, they return a new value. Thus, if you don't assign this to something, `sentence` remains a `String`, `"hello dogs are fast"`, and strings don't have `#pop`.

```
sentence = sentence.split(" ").sort_by {|x| x.length}
```